# C# Garbage Collector - узнать число ссылок на объект и другая полезная информация от GC

Tags: c#, отладка, сборщик-мусора

CG держит число ссылок на объект для удаления данного объекта, но как узнать число ссылок или ещё лучше узнать контекст хранения (где был создан, откуда ссылается)?
Google привёл только к WeakReference, что полезно для отслеживания состояния Alive, но не предоставляет никакой информации о числе ссылок.

Конечная цель - расширенная отладка, хранить таблицу (в идеале граф) созданных объектов разного типа, время создания, время уничтожения (не обязательно), число ссылок, реальный адрес в памяти, фрагментация кучи (с какого по какой адрес ОЗУ используются фрагменты кучи). А так-же выводить этот граф (рисовать через Graphics или отдавать по json - уже отдельная тема). Не все подряд ссылки на определённый тип объекта, как это делают встроенные средства диагностики, а конкретные объекты добавленные в отслеживание из самого кода программы.

Как реализовать данную задачу или по-минимому узнать хотя бы от GC число ссылок на объект? Есть для этих целей в фреймворки необходимые классы? Или отдельные библиотеки/фреймворки?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/debugging/debugging-interfaces

Comment: Это очень обширная задача. Получить ссылки на объект программно можно например через [GcRoot](https://github.com/microsoft/clrmd/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime/src/Common/GCRoot.cs) в ClrMD. Основная сложность в "конкретные объекты добавленные в отслеживание из самого кода программы" - непонятно, идентифицировать отдельные объекты.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Допустим, у меня есть класс MyClass, в различных местах программы я создаю его экземпляры и помещаю их в различные списки. Например var ins1 = new MyClass(), var ins2 = new MyClass(), var ins3 = new MyClass(), из этих экземпляров мне нужен только ins2, т.к. он будет в большом числе списков и будет постоянно добавляться в разные списки и удаляться из них, остальные ins* будут предсказуемы, а за ins2 надо следить, поэтому каким-то образом надо за ним следить, добавить его в некий debug-список и обращаясь к GC получать информацию о объектах из debug-списка.

Comment: Задачу я понял, вопрос в том, что именно добавлять в debug-список. В C# даже нет нормального способа получить адрес произвольного объекта. Есть недокументированный __makeref, но я как-то сомневаюсь, что это хорошая идея. И даже если у нас будет адрес, где гарантия, что он не изменится до момента, когда мы будем сканировать просесс через ClrMD?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight абсолютный реалтайм не требуется, да и к тому-же пока объект в debug-list на него 1 ссылка существует и он не удалится, или можно через WeakReference, на который я наткнулся, и вообще кажется нашёл способ, сейчас накидаю в сообщение, спасибо за подсказку о ClrMD.

Answer (score 2):

Источник: `https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2017/01/03/exploring-.net-managed-heap-with-clrmd.html`
ДеУказателеОбъектизатор: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/53029501/1955772`
Протестировано в `C# Interractive 3.9.0-6.21124.20 (Visual Studio 16.9.1) с Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime 2.0.226801`

Создание экземпляров:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int a { get; set; } = 0;
}
List<MyClass> listA = new List<MyClass>();
listA.Add(new MyClass() { a = 1 });
listA.Add(new MyClass() { a = 2 });
List<MyClass> listB = new List<MyClass>();
listB.Add(new MyClass() { a = 3 });
listB.Add(new MyClass() { a = 4 });
MyClass objectC = new MyClass() { a = 5 };
listA.Add(objectC);
listB.Add(objectC);
List<MyClass> listC = new List<MyClass>();
listC.Add(objectC);
List<MyClass> listD = new List<MyClass>();
listD.Add(objectC);
static List<MyClass> controlList = new List<MyClass>();
controlList.Add(objectC); //objectC = 6 refs
listA.Remove(objectC); //5
objectC = null; //4
GC.Collect();
```

//Подключаем либы

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
#r ".nuget\packages\microsoft.diagnostics.runtime\2.0.226801\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.dll"
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime;
```

//Подключаемся к процессу

```
var dataTarget = DataTarget.AttachToProcess(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, false);
```

// Dump CLR info

```
var clrVersion = dataTarget.ClrVersions.First();
var dacInfo = clrVersion.DacInfo;
Console.WriteLine("# CLR Info");
Console.WriteLine("Version:   {0}", clrVersion.Version);
Console.WriteLine("Filesize:  {0:X}", dacInfo.IndexFileSize);
Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: {0:X}", dacInfo.IndexTimeStamp);
Console.WriteLine("Dac file:  {0}", dacInfo.PlatformSpecificFileName);
```

//Подключаем сборку

```
var runtime = clrVersion.CreateRuntime();
var appDomain = runtime.AppDomains.First();
Console.WriteLine("# Runtime Info");
Console.WriteLine("AppDomain:      {0}", appDomain.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Address:        {0}", appDomain.Address);
Console.WriteLine("Configuration:  {0}", appDomain.ConfigurationFile);
Console.WriteLine("Directory:      {0}", appDomain.ApplicationBase);
```

// Dump thread info

```
Console.WriteLine("## Threads");
Console.WriteLine("Thread count:   {0}", runtime.Threads.Length);
Console.WriteLine("");
foreach (var thread in runtime.Threads)
{
    Console.WriteLine("### Thread {0}", thread.OSThreadId);
    Console.WriteLine("Thread type: {0}", 
                            thread.IsBackground ? "Background" : "Foreground");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Stack trace:");
    foreach (var stackFrame in thread.EnumerateStackTrace())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("* {0}", stackFrame.FrameName);
    }
}
```

//Подключаем Heap

```
var heap = runtime.Heap;
```

//Создаём средство извлечения объекта по указателю

```
public static class AddressHelper
{
    private static object mutualObject;
    private static ObjectReinterpreter reinterpreter;

    static AddressHelper()
    {
        AddressHelper.mutualObject = new object();
        AddressHelper.reinterpreter = new ObjectReinterpreter();
        AddressHelper.reinterpreter.AsObject = new ObjectWrapper();
    }

    public static IntPtr GetAddress(object obj)
    {
        lock (AddressHelper.mutualObject)
        {
            AddressHelper.reinterpreter.AsObject.Object = obj;
            IntPtr address = AddressHelper.reinterpreter.AsIntPtr.Value;
            AddressHelper.reinterpreter.AsObject.Object = null;
            return address;
        }
    }

    public static T GetInstance<T>(IntPtr address)
    {
        lock (AddressHelper.mutualObject)
        {
            AddressHelper.reinterpreter.AsIntPtr.Value = address;
            return (T)AddressHelper.reinterpreter.AsObject.Object;
        }
    }

    // I bet you thought C# was type-safe.
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private struct ObjectReinterpreter
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public ObjectWrapper AsObject;
        [FieldOffset(0)] public IntPtrWrapper AsIntPtr;
    }

    private class ObjectWrapper
    {
        public object Object;
    }

    private class IntPtrWrapper
    {
        public IntPtr Value;
    }
}
```

//Считаем число ссылок и опционально извлекаем объект

```
var numberOfSameTypeObjects = 0;
var uniqueSameTypeObjects = new Dictionary<ulong, int>();
HashSet<ClrType> clrnames = new HashSet<ClrType>();

if (heap.CanWalkHeap)
{
    foreach (var ptr in heap.EnumerateObjects())
    {
        var type = heap.GetObjectType(ptr);
        clrnames.Add(type);
        // Skip if not a string
        if (type == null || !type.Name.Contains(nameof(MyClass)))
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Count total
        numberOfSameTypeObjects++;

        string fixedName = type.Name.Substring(type.Name.LastIndexOf('+') + 1);

        if (fixedName != nameof(MyClass))
        {
            WriteLine($"Error: {type.Name}");
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            WriteLine($"Found: {type.Name}");
        }

        // Get value
        ulong prt_a = ptr.Address;
        MyClass myClassObject = AddressHelper.GetInstance<MyClass>(new IntPtr((long)prt_a));
        if (myClassObject != null)
        {
            WriteLine($"MyClass.a={myClassObject.a}");
        }
        else
        {
            WriteLine($"MyClass convert error");
        }

        if (uniqueSameTypeObjects.ContainsKey(prt_a))
        {
            uniqueSameTypeObjects[prt_a]++;
        }
        else
        {
            uniqueSameTypeObjects[prt_a] = 1;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("## Object info");
    Console.WriteLine("Object count:     {0}", numberOfSameTypeObjects);
    Console.WriteLine("");

    Console.WriteLine("Most duplicated Objects: (top 5)");
    foreach (var keyValuePair in uniqueSameTypeObjects.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value).Take(5))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("* {0} usages: {1}", keyValuePair.Value, keyValuePair.Key);
    }
}
else
{
    WriteLine("Not CanWalkHeap");
}
```

Всё работало со строками, с своими классами - CLRType не знает тип из кода...
error CS0019: Оператор "!=" невозможно применить к операнду типа "ClrType" и "Type".
PS В ClrType.FullName = "Submission#70+MyClass", как вернуть нормальное имя?
Upd переделал, добавив костыль с приведением типа класса к тексту, вроде получилось, вывод:

```
Error: System.Collections.Generic.List<Submission#70+MyClass>
Error: Submission#70+MyClass[]
Found: Submission#70+MyClass
MyClass.a=1
Error: Submission#70+MyClass[]
Found: Submission#70+MyClass
MyClass.a=2
Error: System.Collections.Generic.List<Submission#70+MyClass>
Found: Submission#70+MyClass
MyClass.a=3
Error: Submission#70+MyClass[]
Found: Submission#70+MyClass
MyClass.a=4
Found: Submission#70+MyClass
MyClass.a=5
Error: System.Collections.Generic.List<Submission#70+MyClass>
Error: Submission#70+MyClass[]
Error: System.Collections.Generic.List<Submission#70+MyClass>
Error: Submission#70+MyClass[]
Error: System.Collections.Generic.List<Submission#70+MyClass>
Error: Submission#70+MyClass[]
Error: System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer<Submission#70+MyClass>
## Object info
Object count:     17

Most duplicated Objects: (top 5)
* 1 usages: 74857424
* 1 usages: 74857712
* 1 usages: 75045496
* 1 usages: 75045576
* 1 usages: 75045808
```

Данная попытка - ещё далека до цели, но по крайней мере что-то может.
Большой минус - нельзя сравнить тип напрямую, как это можно исправить?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight остался один косяк, как сравнить CLRType и Type?

Comment: У ClrType есть свойство `MethodTable`. Получите ссылку на таблицу методов у Type (`.TypeHandle.Value`) и сравните их между собой

Comment: "Подключаемся к процессу" - уже неправильно, нельзя напрямую отлаживать собственный процесс. Нужно использовать DataTarget.CreateSnapshotAndAttach, см. https://github.com/microsoft/clrmd/blob/master/doc/GettingStarted.md#attaching-to-a-live-process | "Считаем число ссылок и опционально извлекаем объект" - А GcRoot что, не получилось применить? Почему ручной обход кучи? Ссылки то могут быть не только в куче, но и в статических полях, например.

Comment: "ClrType.FullName = "Submission#70+MyClass", как вернуть нормальное имя?" - Это и есть нормальное имя. Видимо, MyClass вложен в Submission#70. Сравнивать типы вполне нормально по равенству сборки и полного имени, разве что с generics проблема может быть.